# Create a new column in data frame based on the range found in another column and a common column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to create a new column in a data frame based on values from another data frame.

df1 is,

```
Name    Depth
A   100
A   120
B   200
```

df2 is,

```
Name    Start_Depth End_Depth   Zone
A   50  150 Zone1
A   150 200 Zone2
B   50  120 Zone3
B   120 300 Zone4
```

I want to add Zone column in df1, based on two conditions,

1. "Name" should match in both data frames
2. df1.Depth should be between Start_Depth and End_Depth in df2 for same "Name"

Output df1,

```
Name    Depth   Zone
A   100 Zone1
A   120 Zone1
B   200 Zone4
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `df.merge` with `df.query`:

```
In [120]: r = df1.merge(df2).query('End_Depth >= Depth > Start_Depth')[['Name', 'Depth', 'Zone']]

In [121]: r
Out[121]: 
  Name  Depth   Zone
0    A    100  Zone1
2    A    120  Zone1
5    B    200  Zone4
```

OR use `Series.between`:

```
In [114]: x = df1.merge(df2)
In [124]: r = x[x.Depth.between(x.Start_Depth, x.End_Depth)][['Name', 'Depth', 'Zone']]

In [125]: r
Out[125]: 
  Name  Depth   Zone
0    A    100  Zone1
2    A    120  Zone1
5    B    200  Zone4
```

---

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is working for my case. However I would like to know as well what is the best way if I want to do a left join in such cases. For example, I want to keep all the rows from df1 even if it did not find a matching Name or range in df2.

Comment: Just do `df1.merge(df2, how='left')` . In this case `df1` becomes your `left` df.

Comment: df1.merge(df2, on ='Name', how='left', indicator=True).query('(_merge == "left_only") | ((Depth >= Start_Depth ) & (Depth < End_Depth))')  .  I tried this, but it work only if "Name" does not exist in df2, but what if the  "name" exists but "Depth" does not exist in df2 Start/End_Depth range. consider in df1 : Name =A    Depth = 20